# How to fix "..{content:" error in crm output

Tags: suitecrm

I've got an page output `..{content:` instead of request output on some standart modules such as Email notifications.

I noticed that it happens when the url contains `...ajax=...`. 
When I remove all ajax in url and remain the core(`...modules="..."&action=...`) all works fine. 
I've try to turn on and turn off AJAX support of modules. It doesn't help.

The examples of the url string:

http://www.localhost/suitecrm/index.php?action=ajaxui#ajaxUILoc=index.php%3Fmodule%3DOutboundEmailAccounts%26action%3Dindex

Any help would be usefull.

I have already read simular [question](https://community.sugarcrm.com/thread/18885) but answers doesn't help.

Comment: Have you disabled AjaxUI for these modules? It happens when you echo some contents which break then AjaxUI JS logic.

Comment: Yes, i have already disabled all modules. It doesn't help

Comment: what you have disabled? also, check server and suitecrm error logs?